# DIAL-launched app closes immediately (Xbox One Dev Mode)

Tags: launch, xbox-one, dev-mode

I'm developing a receiver app for my company to run on the xbox one and we need it to launch from a mobile device. The xbox is in dev mode and I have added the DIAL declaration to my app's manifest.

I can send an M-SEARCH request to get the location of the xbox's dial service and can do a GET to the dial service to find out the state of my app.

The problem arises when I try to POST to the app url in order to launch it. The POST returns `201 Created` but the app quits after the splash screen.

I thought I had configured my app incorrectly, so I pulled the [Advanced Casting](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AdvancedCasting) sample and deployed it the the xbox but the behavior is the same.

There's very little help available for using DIAL in conjunction with the xbox and this scenario is mentioned nowhere.

Has anyone else run into this or have any experience that might help?

**EDIT**: Leaving DevMode and launching YouTube or NetFlix via DIAL works (that is, they stay launched after the splash screen)...